# Pre-Drawing Raphael screens, save them to file and load at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, svg, raphael

I´m new to Raphael and would like to do some basic questions on how to architect my app:

I need to draw models on a visual graphical editor and save them to files (I call them screens). At runtime, I need to load these screens and animate them from server data using Ajax.

Using SVG I can load data using this simple command:

```
<object id="svgobject" type="image/svg+xml" data=".\svg\svgfilename.svg"></object>
```

Also, on SVG, we can use some graphical visual editors and that´s all we need to built the screens. The rest if javascript code to get element ids and change their attributes at runtime based on ajax call to get server data.

As SVG is not supported on old browser, one natural choice is to go for Raphael, but I don´t know if there is visual graphic editor that support Raphael scripting language and how to save/load these scripts at runtime.

So, What would be the best approach to visual edit my models, save them to a file and load at realtime using Raphael ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ian's answer is one solution. The other way of doing this is to convert SVG documents to a data structure that Raphael can understand.

For relatively simple SVG images you can use [svg2path](https://github.com/eckoit/svg2path). It converts SVG files (or svg from a URL) to paths that can be loaded into Raphael. From the documentation, running the following on the command line:

```
svg2path some.svg
```

generates a path file called `some.path` that can be loaded in Raphael (presumably using the `paper.path()` method).

It's available on [github](https://github.com/eckoit/svg2path) and [npm](https://npmjs.org/package/svg2path).

Comment: Interesting, hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a plugin like https://github.com/wout/raphael-svg-import or https://github.com/jspies/raphael.serialize https://github.com/crccheck/raphael-svg-import-classic to get you started maybe. I think you may need to do some extra work to cope with groups and Raphael.

Edit to clarify, I'm not sure from your other comments what you mean by Raphael Mode from a graphic editor. You can just the graphic as a straight SVG and import. I'm not sure why there needs to support Raphael scripting.

Comment: There are two strategies - you can either make Raphael parse SVG like you suggest or make your vector editor output JSON data that Raphael can understand.

Answer (score 0):

The [**`VectorEditorJS`**](https://code.google.com/p/jsvectoreditor/) is a nice starting point for you.Look into `editor.js` to build or rebuild your own functionality over it.[**`Here's`**](http://jsvectoreditor.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html) a demo.

**EDIT**

The [**`SVGEdit`**](https://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/) demo has got code to save the vector as an svg.You can look into the code.